# How to get hibernate session within method with @Async annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring 4.0.5

I want to perform some db operation using @Async method but the data is not getting saved, when I remove the @Async annotation it works fine.

I know the problem is because hibernate session is not available in the new thread. Can any one know the solution for the same, what exactly I need to do.

Here is the code snippet

```
Controller.java

taskExecutorService.insertLoginDetails(data);


TaskExecutorService.java

@Async
public void insertLoginDetails(LoginDetail data) {
  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(data);
}
```

thanks,
-bond

Comment: Can't you just annotate your method `@Transactional`? There is no reason why this can't work.

Comment: I tried using both Async + Transactional, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix `@Async` and `@Transactional` methods, delegate `@Transactional` method to new component